# Convert Jquery-Ajax to native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have the following code in jquery-ajax that is working fine

```js
ajaxHandler = {
    defaultAttributes: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'index.php/request',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {},
      success: null,
      error: function(data) {
        errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
      },
      timeout: function() {
        errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
      }
    },
    sendRequest: function(attributes) {
      $.ajax(attributes);
    }
```

Now i want to convert this to native JavaScript Code and i am doing this and 403 error is occur and i am unable to get response.

let me know what changes i have to make to make it working like above code(using jquery-ajax)

```js
ajaxHandler = {
    defaultAttributes: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'index.php/request',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {},
      success: null,
      error: function(data) {
        errorHandler.showError('An Error occurred while trying to retreive your requested data, Please try again...');
      },
      timeout: function() {
        errorHandler.showError('The request has been timed out, Please check your Internet connection and try again...');
      }
    },
    sendRequest: function(attributes) {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
      xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
          var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          console.log(jsonResponse);
          attributes.success(attributes.data);
        } else {
          console.log(xmlhttp.responseType);
          console.log(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseXML));
          console.log(xmlhttp);

        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open(attributes.type, attributes.url);
      xmlhttp.send(attributes.data);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need `xmlhttp.responseType` or `xmlhttp.overrideMimeType`.

Comment: @KevinB i have try but this is not the reson. look at the code is the code is fine

Comment: For the most part yea, other than the two lines i mentioned not making much sense. This is a very simple GET request you're testing, it shouldn't be this difficult to replicate, and shouldn't require many options being passed to xmlhttp.

Comment: Step one of debugging this should have been to press F12 and go to the network tab. If you've already done that, you should have included that (the request headers and request body specifically) in your question.

Comment: @KevinB http://localhost/CoutAllure/CoutAllure/Webapp/index.php/request/getallfeatures    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)  this is the error it shows.

Comment: I need to see the request headers, not the error text.

Comment: here is reqest header date: mon, 19 oct 2015 15:29:15 gmt
server: apache/2.4.7 (ubuntu)
connection: close
x-powered-by: php/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13
content-length: 1069
content-type: text/html

Comment: that looks like response headers.

Comment: Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=lops5p3uqb2tpkpivcs0rjl2p1
Host:localhost
Referer:http://localhost/CoutAllure/CoutAllure/Webapp/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36

Comment: All looks fine to me, assuming the url is correct.